# Unable to get WPF Sound Visualization Library working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've recently begun work on an audio application using C#.NET. I've begun some basic implementation of the NAudio library which I intend to use throughout the project. While looking at NAudio's documentation on CodePlex I found a link to the [WPF Sound Visualization Library](http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/), I was attracted by one of its features in particular which I knew I would require in my app.
So I downloaded and added it to my project References.
I've copied how it is referenced within a window's XAML document, like so:

```
xmlns:svl="clr-namespace:WPFSoundVisualizationLib;assembly=WPFSoundVisualizationLib"
```

and then tried to add a control within the library using:

```
<svl:WaveformTimeline x:Name="testWaveformTimeline"/>
```

The problem is that the designer/XMAL editor claims: "svl:WaveformTimeline" does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:WPFSoundVisualizationLib;assembly=WPFSoundVisualizationLib".

Now I know that it does exist. I can make reference to the WaveformTimeline object in the class file, and the object shows up in Visual Studio's Object Browser.

I'm not at all sure why this is the case. If anyone knows any possible solutions to this, or things I should check any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have this problem all the time and it seems to be a bug in Visual Studio because (at least my programs) do compile and work fine. I have not found any solution for that problem and it seems to happen whenever you use classes from a custom namespace.

Comment: Do you use the same target framework as the WPF Sound Visualization Library?

Comment: I was originally using .Net 4.5 then thought that that was the problem, since then I have reverted back to 4.0 (Which is what it was targeted at) and still had the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just found the solution:
By right-clicking on the WPFSoundVisualizationLib .dll I had to 'unblock' the file which had been marked as 'unsafe' by windows because the file were coming from a WebSite. Weird but it was obviously the reason I couldn't use the WaveformTimeLine in my project. A bit late but maybe still worths to post it.

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx